# Recommended way of using spock DetachedMockFactory

Tags: spock

DetachedMockFactory documentation mentions this -

> In order to be usable those Mocks must be manually attached to the
> Specification using MockUtil#attachMock(Object, Specification) and
> detached afterwards MockUtil#detachMock(Object)}.

I have been using it like below where I autowire JavaMailSender in specification class; basically I am not using attachMock or detachMock. I wonder if I am doing something wrong? documentation is not clear to me.

```
def mockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()

@Bean
JavaMailSender testJavaMailSender() {
    return mockFactory.Mock(org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl)
}
```

Comment: The reason I posted this Q is that I am troubleshooting intermittent bug which only occurs on CI server, and this is one thing which I don't understand how its supposed to work.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting on it. And please don't just post a snippet without any context but a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so the people trying to help you can reproduce your problem. Thank you.

Comment: I don't want help with resolving the issue. I am seeking clarification on the documentation. I made the comment jic someone is wondering why am I asking this Q.

Comment: See http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_mocks as long as you use the `spock-spring` extension it will take care of attaching/detaching for you.

Comment: Thanks @LeonardBrünings exactly what I was looking for.